# mysql - check if a group of elements are included in another group

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following setup:

An array in php like this:

```
 $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

A query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT `epicThing` FROM `epicTable` AS `epic`
 WHERE
     SELECT `ids` FROM `someTable` 
     WHERE `epic`.`somethingSomething` = `someTable`.`somethingElse`
     (<<<< HERE IS MY PROBLEM >>>>)
```

The subquery returns something like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).

Now what I need to check is that each of the elements from the array is in that returned answer of the subquery.

Basically something like

```
 SELECT `epicThing` FROM `epicTable` AS `epic`
 WHERE
     '1' IN (
         SELECT `ids` FROM `someTable` 
         WHERE `epic`.`somethingSomething` = `someTable`.`somethingElse`
      )
 AND 
     '2' IN (
         SELECT `ids` FROM `someTable` 
         WHERE `epic`.`somethingSomething` = `someTable`.`somethingElse`
      )
 AND
     '3' IN (
         SELECT `ids` FROM `someTable` 
         WHERE `epic`.`somethingSomething` = `someTable`.`somethingElse`
      ).......
```

But for each element.

For simplicity let's assume that elements are always in order (because I will probably need to convert the array to string), if is not possible otherwise. But I would prefer a general solution if available.

What I DON'T want to do is to get data in php and check it there (this is only a really really small part of a huge query).

Comment: What should happen if the array doesn't contain all of the values of the subquery? A specific event? You could easily change the query to grab all of the records that match what's in your original array, but it's not guaranteed that they would all would match to a record in the database. If they don't all match, the only way to trigger an event would be in PHP.

Comment: Can you give a real object example instead of 'epicThing' because I don't even get what you need. I bet there is a very simple solution

Comment: @spaceman What you said is indeed very simple, but I need it the other way around. I don't need to get all that verify, I need to see if there are enough records to verify.

Comment: @DanFromGermany what I need to do is to see if each of elements in a group exist in the result of a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think this would be the easiest way for you to test that all IDs in your array match to a record in the database:

```
<?php
    $myArray = array(1,2,3);
    $myArrayCount = count($myArray);

    // Convert array for the query
    $queryArray = implode(",", $myArray);

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(YourTable.id)) AS count
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YourTable.id IN ($queryArray)
    HAVING count = $myArrayCount;

?>
```

Mysql will return empty results if the **HAVING count = $myArrayCount;** does not match the number of IDs you are checking for.